# byte[] returns random characters for only numbers and upper case letters

Tags: java, android, mobile, rfid

Currently using an RFID scanner to pull data and send it to a CSV file.  Everything is working except the data being returned is not correct in some cases. If I scan a tag's USER bank that is lower case letters only, it returns the data normally (ie scan: abc, return: abc).

However, if I scan a tag with numbers or upper case letters, it returns random symbols.

[image: screenshot of unexpected text]

Code relevant to getting the data is below:

```
@Override
public void onReadResultReceived(final ReadResult readResult) {


    if (readResult.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_OK) {
        mHandler.post(() -> {
            synchronized (mInventoryResultsLock) {
                // Read the memory bank.

                if (readResult.getStatus() == Status.STATUS_OK) {
                    byte[] bankData = readResult.getBankData();

                    String str = new String(bankData);

                    appendText(str);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried using StandardCharsets when converting the byte[] to a string and all the different options but the same thing happens.

Is there something I am missing?  I don't understand why the behavior would be different for lower case letters vs numbers or upper case.  Is there something I am misunderstanding about how a byte[] works?

Comment: Try printing out the bytes you get and look at the result.  My guess is that the RFID device or its driver is not actually using a standard encoding, and you will have to consult its documentation to determine what it is actually doing.

Comment: Would probably be more fruitful to follow up the company that makes this RFID scanner to get more information about using your device than what we can provide here...

Comment: Please embed images into the posts where possible, instead of providing links to images. That makes your question presentable and easy to read

Comment: @HoRn This user doesn't have the reputation to do that.

Comment: `StandardCharsets` Why not tell which ones? And how?

Comment: Check if you hit a ASCII<>UTF8 problem